# Visual Studio Team Services Build - Error 500 (was Visual Studio Online - VSO)

Tags: azure, tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I don't know how to change or track the agent, or identify the reason of this error.

C:\a\1\s\RadMVCLab\Scripts\jquery.datatables\examples\examples_support\themes\smoothness\images\ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec_1x400.png: Please contact your administrator. There was an error contacting the server.
Technical information (for administrator):
HTTP code 500: Internal Server Error
System.Exception: One or more errors occurred while performing a get operation for workspace ws_1_1;1c6d9554-2472-4494-8d67-d17901ca66b2
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.TfvcGetOperation.Execute(String sourceVersion)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.TfvcHelper.SyncRepository(VersionControlServer server, Uri repositoryUrl, String workspaceName, String rootPath, WorkingFolder[] workingFolders, String sourceVersion, Boolean cleanRepository, String shelveset, String reshelveName, Boolean gatedRunCI, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.TfvcHelper.Sync(ITaskEndpoint endpoint, String localPath, Dictionary`2 serverPathMapping, String sourceVersion, Boolean cleanRepository, String workspaceName, String shelveset, String reshelveName, Boolean runCI, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Plugin.Build.TfvcSourceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<PrepareRepositoryAsync>b__0()
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Common.AgentExecutionTerminationException: Prepare repository failed with exception. ---> System.Exception: One or more errors occurred while performing a get operation for workspace ws_1_1;1c6d9554-2472-4494-8d67-d17901ca66b2
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.TfvcGetOperation.Execute(String sourceVersion)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.TfvcHelper.SyncRepository(VersionControlServer server, Uri repositoryUrl, String workspaceName, String rootPath, WorkingFolder[] workingFolders, String sourceVersion, Boolean cleanRepository, String shelveset, String reshelveName, Boolean gatedRunCI, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.TfvcHelper.Sync(ITaskEndpoint endpoint, String localPath, Dictionary`2 serverPathMapping, String sourceVersion, Boolean cleanRepository, String workspaceName, String shelveset, String reshelveName, Boolean runCI, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Plugin.Build.TfvcSourceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Plugin.Build.TfvcSourceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

---

Finishing Build

---

Comment: Can you open that image file from "Code" explorer correctly?

Comment: So this issue does not always occur?

Comment: Yes, and this error occurred 3 times, every time about a different file and all files was ok in the Source Control Explorer.

Comment: Well, I couldn't go further than that. I am stuck in this error.

Comment: Can you try to deploy a on-premise build agent to see if it can get the source file successfully:https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/agents/windows ?

Comment: Do you mean use the XAML template instead the portal version?

Comment: No, I mean following the link to install the build agent on your local machine and then still use the same build definition but choose your local build agent when queue the build.

Comment: I didn't know that this was possible, I will try, thanks!